# ViewPager with Fragment reload at first and last page

Tags: android, callback, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to create a `ViewPager` with six fragments but only 2nd fragment to 5th fragment contain data that I want to show and the first fragment and the last fragment I want to be used to reload the data and set the position to the 2nd fragment again. The overall flow is like this :

1st (reload and go back to 2nd) <- 2nd fragment <-> 5th fragment -> 6th fragment (same with 1st)

what I've tried is I create a callback from the 1st fragment and 6th fragment like this

```
public static class callbackFragmentLoading implements callbackFragmentLoad {

    @Override
    public void onLoading() {
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(2,false);
    }

}
```

and I passed the callback to the fragment constructor so I can called the onLoading function in the onActivityCreated. But I everytime I do it the application will be force closed and the logcat shows

> recursive entry to executependingtransactions

is there any way to do this? or my method for doing it is wrong?

Thank You

Comment: Are you trying to implement something like swipe left/right to refresh?

Comment: @Luksprog yes! something like that! do you have any other idea to do that? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any way to do this? or my method for doing it is wrong?

Messing with callbacks between `Fragments` of a `ViewPager` isn't probably such a good idea. Instead I would do it like this:

- Don't load any data(like with a `Loader`) in the `Fragments` from the `ViewPager`, instead let the `FragmentActivity` do it(and the `Fragments` will get it through methods from the `Activity`).
- Your two loading fragments(position `0` and `5`) will call in their `onResume` method a reload action on the parent `Activity`(like a `Loader` restart)
- At this moment the `Activity` will load/reload the data and when that finishes it will set the `ViewPager` to the correct items(either `1` or `4`)
- in the `onResume` method of the data fragments you'll refresh the fragment's data(here you may need to use some sort of signaling system because you'll need to duplicate the refresh code in the `onCreateView`(some fragments may have their view destroyed if they are far apart from the current visible position)).

As I don't know many things about the inner data fragment I've written a [basic skeleton sample](https://gist.github.com/4335109)(without the data loading in the activity).

Comment: I'll try to implement this and report the result to you! I'll mark the answer right after that, thank you luksprog!

Comment: your code is working well,but at the first fragment (position 0) the on resume isn't always called, I wonder why? now I'm trying to figure it out

Comment: not yet I've tried to override onStart() but sometimes it also won't be called

Comment: @NAYOSO `onResume` will be called but it could get called when you get(and watch) the fragment 1. But I think you could easily bypass this by using a `OnPageChangeListener` and moving the code from `onResume` to the `onPageSelected` callback of the interface.