# Android - Android tab and page layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

I want to build a view that have 3 different view that can be accessed from the bottom button. One of the view have a tab-like view that can be swiped. It looks like this :

```
     ________________________________
    |     Tab 1    |      Tab 2      |
    |______________|_________________|
    |                                |
    |                                |
    |                                |
    |                                |
    |                                |
    |         View Pager             |
    |                                |
    |                                |
    |                                |
    |                                |
    |                                |
    |                                |
    |________________________________|
    |         |             |        |
    |    1    |       2     |    3   |
    |_________|_____________|________|
```

I'm planning to use fragment to switch the view from view 1,2,3 (button)
in the mid I'm trying to use view pager what I'm still not sure is how do I design the view pager? I'll show a view with 6 grid and it'll contain image and it can be clicked. For first I'm planning to did it like this question -> [ViewPager with Fragment reload at first and last page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945520/viewpager-with-fragment-reload-at-first-and-last-page) but there's still a bug in the first page, if I'm trying to always add the page dynamically I'm afraid it'll causing out of memory problem. What do you guys think about it? is there any other solution?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this tutorial and helful for code,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html